# How to update Github pages' index.html file

Tags: github, updates, github-pages, 2048

I have made some changes in the forked public project.. I then made my own changes. I have run locally and everything was fine.. Only except the index.html file all changes I have made works.. How to update changes of index.html file and post it into pages?
github page: https://imshivamagrawal.github.io/2048/

Comment: Why can't you change the `index.html` page the same way you changed the other pages?

Comment: There is no problem. All your commits are reflected in your index page.